# py4j.Py4JException: Method splits([]) does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, py4j

I get the following error when executing my spark job:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o191.splits. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method splits([]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:272)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my code:

```
points = df.rdd.map(lambda x: ( (x['col1'], x['col2'], x['col3']), x[i + '_func']))
points.cache()
dim = points.first()[1].size
print points._jrdd.splits().size()
```

The last line throws the above-provided exception. How can I solve this error?
This code worked well in Spark 1.6. Now I am working with Spark 2.2 and I get this error. The version of Python is 2.7.12 (the same as previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splits` in Java have been deprecated since 1.1.0 (replaced with `partitions`) and shouldn't be used in PySpark at all. use [`getNumPartitions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.getNumPartitions)

```
points.getNumPartitions()
```